# Is KeyboardInterrupt raised even if the program uses threading or external modules?

Tags: python-3.x

I have this project I'm working on. It's equivalent to this:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
import threading, library.modules
def engine():
    ...
def stop():
    ...
try:
    engine()
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    stop()
```

I would like it to cleanly quit at any moment if the user decides to do this by interrupting.

What I'd like to know is if `KeyboardInterrupt` is raised when it's running `engine()`, will `stop()`  always be executed even if `engine()` uses `threading` or an external module from `modules`?